# import {UIRouter} from "ui-router-ng2"; reference generates thousands of errors on build

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015, angular2-routing

Trying to get routing work. And configuring router in router.config.ts but when i add

```
import {UIRouter} from "ui-router-ng2";
```

A have tonns of syntax errors:

\Source..node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.d.ts   18720   Active
Error   TS1128  Declaration or statement expected.  TypeScript Virtual Projects ..\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.d.ts 18720   Active
Error   TS1109  Expression expected.    ...\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.d.ts    18720   Active

i am usging VS20015 UPDATE 3

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by not using ui-router-ng2 and using 
    "@angular/router": "3.1.0-beta.0"

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/router": "3.1.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ui-router-visualizer": "^2.0.7",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.11",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.2",
    "typings": "^1.3.2"
  }
}
```